# compressing js and css files using yui compressor

Tags: javascript, css, yui-compressor

I was testing combining css and js files and that seem to be easy using this command line:

**for css files:**

```
sudo cat *.css > combined.css
```

**for js files:**

```
 sudo cat *.js > combined.js
```

The weird part is that the compression result don't seem to be as I thought. I compared the results through this command:

```
wc combined.css combined.min.css
```

***And got this result:***

```
727325 combined.css
716052 combined.min.css
```

now I'm wondering is that all I can do? does that reflect a real result? I mean I see some tests around the net and it shows around 60% difference.

any idea what's going on??

**Update:**

This is the command used to compress the files:

```
java -jar /usr/share/yui-compressor/yui-compressor.jar combined.css -o combined.min.css
```

Comment: You need to show the command you're using to actually compress them.

Comment: you wont get as much compression from css as you will with js as all it really does is remove white space.

Comment: Is there CSS files from frameworks in your combined.css ?

Comment: if I use css minifier I get smaller css file...!! how is that possible?? does the css minifier remove extra stuff in this case that Yui compressor can't remove?

Comment: @neomega,no not at all... no frameworks css..

Comment: Overuse of url(data:image/...) ?

Comment: I don't have any single data:imgae urls in my css... none